# Matching SSNs with RegEx

Tags: regex

I am filtering out SSN#’s for a project. The product’s default expressions for SSNs is

```
(^|\b)(?!9|8|77[3-9]|666|000)(\d{3})( - | |-)(?!00)(\d{2})\3(?!0000)(\d{4})(\b|$)
```

There was a modification in the past for the their customized script with regex expression:

```
(^|\b)(?!9|8|77[3-9]|666|000)(\d{3})( - | |-)(?!00)(\d{2})\3(?!0000)(\d{4})($|[^\d-])
```

The difference between the two expressions is

```
(\b|$)
\b: backspace
$:end of string
```

And

```
($|[^\d-])
$:end of string
[^]: Not in position
\d-: not match 0-9
```

I guess this does not make sense to me. Why was the change made? Both of the end of these expressions seem superfluous. Any help would be most appreciated.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The the difference here:

```
(\b|$)
```

vs

```
($|[^\d-])
```

`\b` only represents the backspace character within a character class like `[\babc]` would match 'a', 'b', 'c', or a backspace char.  Outside a character class, which is what is seen here, it is a word break, such as a between a letter and a space.

Previously, the regex could accept SSN, matching the pattern up to that point, ending with the end of the string (`$`), or with any word break (`\b`).  So it would match the SSN in "111-22-3333" or "111-22-3333 garbage data"

After the change, it is generally more permissive of what follows the SSN.  It can end with the end of the string (`$`), or any character other than a digit or hyphen (`[^\d-]`).  So, as well as what was matched above, it would also match the SSN in "111-22-3333garbage" or "111-22-3333#6789", but not in "111-22-33333" or "111-22-3333-123"

Frankly, the old version you list seems more correct for most cases to me, but that would depend on the needs for your application, of course.